# How to run migrations on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Sometimes I see a pop-up, that I can migrate to a newer kotlin version or something but I recently accidentally closed it and after restarting Android Studio it doesn't appear again. How can I run that migrations manually? Because, when I download a random project from GitHub I sometimes get compilation errors if something is not updated.

Comment: From SDK manager I think.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom inspection profile to check if your code requires Kotlin migration. Go to bottom toolbar - Problems - Project Errors - Inspect Code (alternatively, Code - Inspect code... in the app bar), press 3 dots next to existing inspection profile, duplicate that existing profile, select only Kotlin - Migration for this new profile and run an inspection for it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the pop-up appear again, try the following:

1. Change `kotlin_version` on your build.gradle to whatever version of Kotlin you were before or want to migrate from.
2. Sync Project with Gradle files.
3. Upgrade again to the version you want to migrate to.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. I'm trying to get the migration wizard to appear for Kotlin 1.6 to 1.7 but after I accidentally dismissed it I can't get it back. Was there something else you recommend?